# NuGet: references to assemblies in runtimes folder not added

Tags: nuget

I have a project that targets two different operating systems/frameworks:

1. `net461` on Windows and
2. `netcoreapp2.0` on OSX

I'm trying to figure out how to correctly package this for NuGet.  According to [this post](https://natemcmaster.com/blog/2016/05/19/nuget3-rid-graph/) I should be able to package them like this:

```
/runtimes/win/lib/net461/myassembly.dll
/runtimes/osx/lib/netcoreapp2.0/myassembly.dll
```

By when I add the NuGet package to another project, the packaged assemblies aren't added as references to the target project.

Then I read somewhere that you also need to add reference libraries to the `/ref` folder so I tried this:

```
/runtimes/win/lib/net461/myassembly.dll
/runtimes/osx/lib/netcoreapp2.0/myassembly.dll
/ref/net461/myassembly.dll
/ref/netcoreapp2.0/myassembly.dll
```

In this case the assemblies get added as a reference to the target project and I can build it, but the required assemblies aren't copied to the output folder.

The documentation on all this is extremely vague and I'm fairly lost.

What am I missing?

---

Associated NuGet Issue: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/7316

---

Update: I've put together a [sample project](https://bitbucket.org/toptensoftware/multitargettest) that demonstrates what I'm trying to achieve.  In particular see the bottom of the readme, titled "NuGet Packaging".

Comment: Do you mean `myassembly.dll` is added as a reference but it isn't copied to output directory?

Comment: When it's included in the 'ref' folder yes - it's added as reference but not copied to output directory.  When just in runtimes folder, then it's neither added as reference nor copied to output.

Comment: how are you creating the NuGet package? Manually? Can you share the .nuspec file? Also, can you try adding "lib" folder as well (similar to "ref" folder); e.g., `/lib/net461/myassembly.dll`?

Comment: @TheBlueSky  See the linked sample project in the original question - there's a nuspec there.  I've tried with 'ref' and 'lib' folders with no luck so far.  https://bitbucket.org/toptensoftware/multitargettest

Comment: When I had both the lib and the ref folders, the net461 project output got a copy of .dll, but the .netcoreapp2.0 build didn't.  Also it didn't bring in the other files from the runtimes folder - just the ones in the lib and/or ref folder (not sure).

Comment: Pretty sure I read somewhere (but can't find it now) that files that are only needed for implementation (eg: the OsxOnlyLibrary project in my sample project) only need to be included in the runtimes folder - not the lib or ref folder - but they're definitely not getting copied to the output folder for me.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is what I've finally figured out/guessed (because as best I can tell there's no official documentation for some of this)

- Files added to the /runtimes folder aren't automatically added as references to the target project.
- The /ref and /runtime folder should be used in conjunction with each other and only for the .NET Core target.  As best I can .NET Framework targets apparently don't support these folders.
- The /ref folder is for compile time references and anything added here will be added as a reference to the target project.
- Assemblies in the /ref folder don't need to have an implementation - every public API could just throw a not implemented exception.  In practice however you typically just take a copy of one of the implementation assemblies and declare it as the compile time API.
- I've read (but haven't tested myself) that assemblies in the /ref folder must be "Any CPU" builds.  You can use CorFlags utility to patch an implementation assembly for this if necessary.
- The /runtimes folder is used to provide an implementation assemblies for any references included in the /ref folder.  These assemblies are used at runtime and during deployment.
- The /runtimes folder can include additional assemblies that are only required at runtime and don't need to be seen by the client project.  These additional assemblies won't be included as references in the target project but will be available for run/deployment.
- As mentioned by others, the files in the /runtimes folder aren't copied to the output folder of the build. Instead config files are placed there that tell the runtime how to locate the /runtimes files from the NuGet cache.
- For .NET Framework targets (ie: net461) just use the /lib folder as there's no other runtimes for .NET aside from Windows anyway.

Putting this all together, my original example, should have looked like this:

```
/lib/net461/myassembly.dll                       (net461/Windows Compile and Runtime)
/runtimes/osx/lib/netcoreapp2.0/myassembly.dll   (netcore/OSX Runtime)
/runtimes/win/lib/netcoreapp2.0/myassembly.dll   (netcore/Win Runtime)
/ref/netcoreapp2.0/myassembly.dll                (netcore/* Compile Time)
```

Comment: You'll find a fair amount of official documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/supporting-multiple-target-frameworks#architecture-specific-folders).

Answer (score 13):

I spent a fair amount of time trying your project on OSX in both Visual Studio for Mac and VS Code.  I'll try to stick with factual observations without getting into "why don't you do X instead".

- The `runtimes/{rid}/lib/{tfm}/*.dll` paths look ok
- `target="lib/{tfm}/..."` assemblies are automatically referenced, `runtimes/...` are not
- Using target framework of `netstandard` seems like it would make your package work in both `netcoreapp` and `netstandard` projects (e.g. use `target="lib/netstandard1.6/..."`).  Compare [with this](http://nugettoolsdev.azurewebsites.net/4.2.0/get-nearest-framework?project=netstandard1.6&package=netcoreapp2.0)
- `runtimes/` seems to be intended for platform-dependent assemblies you'll load at runtime.  For example, 32/64-bit native assemblies in `runtimes/win-x64/native/` and `runtimes/win-x86/native/`) loaded with [`AssemblyLoadContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.loader.assemblyloadcontext?view=netcore-2.1) ([another post by McMaster](https://natemcmaster.com/blog/2018/07/25/netcore-plugins/))
- Using separate slns for Windows and OSX, or separate platform-specific projects that reference platform-agnostic projects (like [Xamarin](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/xamarin/)) would obviate some of the configuration wrangling
- I found no documentation on `target="ref/..."`, but you can add [Explicit Assembly `<references>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec#explicit-assembly-references) (inside the nuspec `<metadata>` block)
- Packaged assemblies won't appear in the output directory, but when prepared for distribution with `dotnet publish` they'll be included:
  [image]

Comment: Hi Jake, although you didn't get to the actual answer I was after, you seemed to have spent the most effort on this and covered most of the same points as the other answers so I've given you the bounty.  Thanks for your effort.

Comment: Thanks, I guess my last bullet point ([this short answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52397501/nuget-references-to-assemblies-in-runtimes-folder-not-added/52461004#52461004)) was all you needed.  The `runtimes/` folder is "funny".  I'll mention when you invariably deal with unmanaged code a folder like `runtimes/win-x64/native/` won't get copied with .NET Framework unless you set project > Build > Platform target to __x64__ (or x86).

Comment: @Jake Great! In my case, the problem was that on some project the "Platform target" was "x86" instead of "AnyCPU". By choosing "AnyCPU", all runtime platforms available were copied (in this case it was for Microsoft WebView2 which runs on x86, x64 and arm64).

Answer (score 7):

.NET Core and .NETSTANDARD don't copy dependencies to output directory, they are mapped using deps.json which points to relative paths from local NuGet cache.

Comment: Yes! That's a piece of what I was missing...  I didn't realize that until late last night in a bit of an aha moment.

Comment: @BradRobinson My question in this context, how nuget package gets installed on deployment machine, production box?

Answer (score 1):

This has been a very useful thread to get more information and hints on how to create a NuGet package that references native DLLs, and is consumed in both .NET Framework as well as .NET Core / modern .NET libraries / applications.

My experience so far has been that if this library (let's call it library A) only targets .NET Standard, consuming this library in a .NET Core / 5.0 or 6.0 application does lead to the native assemblies being pulled in correctly from the runtimes folder. In a .NET Framework 4.7 application however, this does not appear to be the case. Unless the runtime is explicitly specified when compiling, e.g.:

```
    dotnet build ... --runtime win-x86
```

When using library A in a .NET Core or .NET 5.0/6.0 application however, this runtime identifier is not required - all runtimes are made available and the right one is selected at runtime.

If you want library A to be consumed in applications that also target .NET Framework, and you don't want the user to have to specify the runtime explicitly, then it seems to be necessary to:

- Target both .NET Standard and .NET Framework
- Ensure that the native assemblies end up in the following folder structure in the NuGet package:

  ```
    "lib/{tfm}/..."
  ```

While the .NET documentation referenced by [tm1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/806690/tm1) earlier [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/supporting-multiple-target-frameworks#architecture-specific-folders) talks about how to get this to work using nuspec files, it is less clear how to do so in the SDK .csproj format. I managed to do this in the [NLoptNet](https://github.com/BrannonKing/) project, see the relevant .csproj file [here](https://github.com/BrannonKing/NLoptNet/blob/df03c72e5707151b8e17041d4c207f28556c137f/NLoptNet/NLoptNet.csproj). Final relevant point (in addition to the two bullets above):

- Use `"<None Include"` rather than `"<None Update"` to add the native assemblies

So far - this works, but there is one quirk - as you can see [here](https://github.com/BrannonKing/NLoptNet/runs/4596203102?check_suite_focus=true#step:8:15) it generates warning MSB3246 when consuming library A in a .NET Framework application. See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48122173/warning-when-using-nuget-package-that-contains-native-dll) Stack Overflow post. This leads me to believe that maybe the above is not the right approach, and therefore to some questions:

- Is this the intended way to consume library A in .NET Core, modern .NET and .NET Framework applications?
- Should one always specify the runtime identifier when using dotnet build / dotnet test?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to target .NET Standard 2.0 instead of net461 and netcoreapp2.0? Libraries built against netstandard2.0 should work with .NET Core 2.0 and .NET Framework 4.6.1: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard

Comment: I can't use netstandard since the real project this is for uses MethodBuilder (and friends) which is outside the scope of netstandard.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the new csproj format? If so it has built in support for multiple target frameworks.

For example running `dotnet pack` against a .csproj file with this content:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">    
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>net461;netcoreapp2.1;netstandard2.0</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>    
</Project>
```

will result in a .nupkg that works for .NET Framework 4.6.1, .NET Core 2.1 and .NET Standard 2.0.

Various trick can then be used to include specific parts for each framework depending on what's available.

Comment: This question is about nuget packaging and getting the assemblies correctly referenced and copied in the target project.

Comment: I've updated my answer to more fully explain the feature I was referring to.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to solve the same problem.
The solution proposed by you works fine, but there is one question ...
The case of Win and net46 is clear. And now I need to add a reference to the assembly in the project for a netcoreapp for the Win and for Linux. The problem is that this is a DIFFERENT assembly with the SAME name. Those my package looks like this:

```
/lib/net461/myassembly1.dll                       (net461/Windows Compile and Runtime)
/runtimes/ubuntu/lib/netcoreapp2.0/myassembly2.dll   (netcore/Ubuntu Runtime)
/runtimes/win/lib/netcoreapp2.0/myassembly1.dll   (netcore/Win Runtime)
/ref/netcoreapp2.0/???
```

Update: Actually, the myassembly1.dll and myassembly2.dll are both called myassembly.dll. But to show that one is assembled for Windows, and the second one for Linux, I will leave here such a name.

The most interesting thing is that I tried to put any assembly in the folder ref, and it works on both Windows and Linux. 
This version works on both systems

```
/lib/net461/myassembly1.dll   
/runtimes/ubuntu/lib/netcoreapp2.0/myassembly2.dll 
/runtimes/win/lib/netcoreapp2.0/myassembly1.dll  
/ref/netcoreapp2.0/myassembly1.dll
```

And this too

```
/lib/net461/myassembly1.dll   
/runtimes/ubuntu/lib/netcoreapp2.0/myassembly2.dll 
/runtimes/win/lib/netcoreapp2.0/myassembly1.dll  
/ref/netcoreapp2.0/myassembly2.dll
```

But I think this is not right and I was wrong somewhere.

Comment: The trick is to realize that the /ref folder isn't used at runtime - only at compile time.  It should "define" the api and the files in the /runtimes folder should implement the same API.  So assuming both assembly 1 and 2 implement the same api you can use either in the /ref folder.

Comment: I updated my message, although as I understand from your comment, it does not matter.
In that case, why if I put an empty file "myassembly.dll" in the ref/ folder , nothing will work?
If you open the Microsoft packages (stored in the local cache), then there are empty files in the ref\ folder with the name "_._"