# Unable to add NetVips via NuGet in my VS project

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

I'm trying to use the [NetVips library](https://libvips.github.io/libvips/2018/04/10/libvips-for-dot-net.html) in my VB.NET project, i've added the NetVips.Native.win-x86 in my project from NuGet, the issue is that instead of adding the reference to the Bin folder it's add the NetVips.Native.win-x86 in a folder inside bin called packages and when i'm trying to reference to the library methods in the project i'm unable to...

[image]

And if i try manually to add the references to all the NetVips dll i get the error that it's unable to reach assembly or COM.

So how can i make NetVips work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is normal behavior.

The `NetVips.Native.win-x86` nuget package's `runtimes` folder's dlls are not the type of **COM**. Only **COM** dlls can be referenced under the project. They are native binaries.

[image]

**And** these three dlls are not for assembly references from the author's design.

**And** that is the folder `runtimes` folder's function. See [this document](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52471739/6593065).

These three dlls from the `runtimes` folder provide the necessary services for your application when your project is running and deployed. It is just that these three dlls are not the type of **COM**, which caused your problem.

**Instead**, you should use [NetVips](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NetVips/) nuget package. The dlls from it are the type of **COM**. And you can use it.

## Update

use Release mode, then move dlls like `libvips-42.dll` ... from `runtimes` folder into `bin` folder, get it.

Comment: My purpose is to use the [NetVips](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NetVips/) but it depends of libvips-42.dll which is not provided with that package, anyway i solved by moving the dlls from runtimes to bin and it solved the issue in release

Comment: Well. Thanks for your feedback. Be glad to know that you have solved your issue by yourself. And I have added your workaround into my answer and you can check it. Anyway, have a nice day!